# what is the easiest way to print an image on screen on java?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, javax.imageio

what is the easiest way to print a BufferedImage object (an image) on screen in java eclipse?
iv red some ways but those are so much in detail:

```
BufferedImage img=...
```

Comment: It is inherently complex to place an image on the screen because a supporting UI element is required to display the image.

Answer (score 2):

For Swing...

Use a `JLabel`, see [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details.

To read an image use `ImageIO.read`, see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

You will need to wrap the resulting `BufferedImage` in an `ImageIcon` before you can set it to the `JLabel`...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```